# Create a script for check directory size

Tags: scripting, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi which is running Raspbian. My SD card has only 16GB of space, so after some time the log inside `/var/log` uses all the space on the SD. I almost can't do anything with my Raspberry Pi, so I tried to create a script for checking `/var/log` directory dimension every day and send me a mail with this data, so I can delete some logs when too much space is used. I have a problem with the `du -h /var/log` because my script doesn't execute it.

This is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=/var/log
folder_size="du -h /var/log"
maxsize=10000000
emailAddr="mymail@gmail.com"
while true; do
  if [ $folder_size -ge $maxsize ]; then
    echo size is over $maxsize kilobytes
    subject="DIMENSIONE DELLA CARTELLA $folder HA SUPERATO IL LIMITE!"
    echo "La dimensione della cartella $folder ha superato il limite di $maxsize" | mail -s "$subject" $emailAddr
    exit
  else
    echo size is under $maxsize kilobytes
    
    subject="dimensione della cartella $folder"
    echo "La dimensione della cartella $folder è di $folder_size - $maxsize" | mail -s "$subject" $emailAddr 
  fi
  sleep 86400 # in seconds = 1 day
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du -h /var/log` (you need to use backticks, or $(xxx), not double quotes) is going to return output such as below.  But you want to determine just the size.

```
# du -h /var/log
2.6M    /var/log/httpd
4.0K    /var/log/ntpstats
14M     /var/log/sa
4.0K    /var/log/mail
26M     /var/log/audit
46M     /var/log
#
```

Whereas if you run `du -s /var/log` you will see output such as

```
# du -s /var/log
46256   /var/log
#
```

So by piping into cut, you can extract the numeric element, as below.

```
# du -s /var/log | cut -f1
46256
#
```

Meaning the line in your script ought to be changed from

```
folder_size="du -h /var/log"
```

to

```
folder_size=`du -s /var/log | cut -f1`
```

Or, to use non-deprecated syntax

```
folder_size=$(du -s /var/log | cut -f1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, there's a way to have, in the mail, the size in GB or, at least in MB instead of byte?

Comment: Yes, other folk have 'been there, done that', have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059944/kb-to-mb-using-bash

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are asking for help with a script. May I suggest an alternative using Logrotate to watch the log(s) and rotate them based on size and the amount of rotated logs that you keep?

Something like this:

```
/tmp/output.log {
    size 100M
    copytruncate
    create 700 root utmp
    rotate 4
    compress
}
```